# Regular Expression Check: return boolean and answers

Tags: arrays, regex, grouping

(Make it short to help others)

1. check if a string matches to a regex:

   ```
   text.range(of: regex, options: .regularExpression) == nil
   ```
2. check string selected part matches:

   ```
   let nsString = self as NSString

   let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern)
   let allMatches = regex
       .matches(in: self, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: nsString.length))
   return allMatches.map { match in
       return (1 ..< match.numberOfRanges)
           .map { matchIndex in
               return nsString.substring(with: match.range(at: matchIndex))
           }
       }
   ```

Comment: The first can just use `text.range(of: regex, options: .regularExpression) != nil`. You don't really need an utility function for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is easy and we don't actually need `NSRegularExpression` for that:

```
extension String {
    func hasMatches(_ pattern: String) -> Bool {
        return self.range(of: pattern, options: .regularExpression) != nil
    }
}

let regex = "(.*) [:] (.*)"
let string = "Tom : how are you?"

print(string.hasMatches(regex))
```

I would say that we don't even need a utility function for that.

The second is harder to understand, mostly because `NSRegularExpression` API is not really converted to Swift and it even uses old `NSString`:

```
extension String {
    func getMatches(_ pattern: String) throws -> [[String]] {
        let nsString = self as NSString

        let expression = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern)
        let matches = expression
            .matches(in: self, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: nsString.length))

        return matches.map { match in
            let numGroups = match.numberOfRanges
            // we are skipping group 0 which contains the pattern itself
            return (1 ..< numGroups)
                .map { groupIndex in
                    return nsString.substring(with: match.range(at: groupIndex))
                }
            }
    }
}

print(try! string.getMatches(regex)) // [["Tom", "how are you?"]]
```

Note that I am returning an array of arrays because the expression can match multiple times.

For example:

```
let regex = "(\\d+):(\\d+)"
let string = "01:23, 02:34"

print(try! string.getMatches(regex)) // [["01", "23"], ["02", "34"]]
```